# Algorithm of Elevators or Lifts

Tags: algorithm

Say, there is single elevator which is at Ground-Level in a building of G+24.

A man on G+7 calls elevator to go down (presses down button).

Ergo, the elevator will show up-arrow till G+7 then toggle to down arrow, as it is supposed to go down from there.

If a man at G+2 presses up arrow button (lift just started moving up and has not crossed G+2),
will elevator/lift actually open at G+2?

if it will, what if person at G+2 presses button to go to G+20?

what will be the path of elevator (as in G -> G+2 -> ...)?

I am very confused how exactly elevators/lifts handle these cases!

Comment: How has this question anything to do with C++?

Comment: This is precisely why so many modern buildings have a panel for choosing your target floor, and not just your intended direction of travel...

Comment: More suitable to https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Elevator controls are actually quite complicated.  I'm sure there are reasonable sources on the web that provide introductions to the topic.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not know what to tag! so tagged C++.

Talking about India, here even in IT parks, There are only two buttons to call a lift, up and down arrow. and once you get into elevator, you choose your floor.

Can you tell in these cases what will happen ?

Comment: It's further complicated in some environments, like hotels, by some users having priority ID on their access cards, eg. cleaners, who otherwise could not get their work done on time.  Similar - VIP's who are paying $$$ for their penthouse rooms.

Comment: Elevator expert Douglas Adams: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/144863-not-unnaturally-many-elevators-imbued-with-intelligence-and-precognition-became

Comment: @PranavSinha No, we can't; it's a policy decision. You can experiment, or ask manufacturers. And you will get different answers/results.

Comment: If there are only two buttons, take the stairs - software devs, who otherwise would sit in their cubicles all day,  need the exercise anyway.

Comment: You can try it yourself: http://play.elevatorsaga.com

Answer (score 2):

As a programmer, you use statistics and modeling (best case) or made-up assumptions based on your own subjective experience.

In your example the programmer would use the assumption (or the statistics) that most people who want to go down want to go down *all the way* to ground level or parking. Couple that with the assumption that people who want to enter an elevator on the 2nd floor (íf the building is a tall one) want to go up.

You would therefore not stop before going as far down as the lowest floor input by the people in the elevator.

Basically, the general answer is you use **statistics** of movements. Those differ between different buildings. If the building is new and there is no data yet you look at what is on the floor and try to make predictions about movements. Basically, you create a *model* of people's movements. Then you try to create an optimization function that minimizes waiting time, for example, or queue size, or energy consumption.

You may also take into account time of day. For example, in a business tower you may optimize for going up during the morning rush hour, and for going down in the late afternoon/early evening.

*Modeling*, simulation and statistics are key to finding good algorithms in such scenarios.

Add to that *conditions*. For example, you may set the condition to the optimization that nobody should wait for longer than 20 seconds, even if the overall efficiency would go down. For example, if all traffic is on the lower floors and there is a single person on on the 50th floor. It might be most efficient to ignore him/her for an hour, but that's not acceptable. Or an elevator that senses it is full may not stop except on the floor selected by people inside of it.

You can find courses on how to do modeling on the Internet, for example. on education sites such as edX. Here is an example (the course is closed but still accessible): ["Mathematical Modeling Basics -- Use mathematics to create models to solve real-life problems."](https://www.edx.org/course/mathematical-modeling-basics-delftx-mathmod1x)

Here is an example for a paper (of which there are many!) on how to model elevators: ["Modeling Elevator System With Coloured Petri Nets"](http://worldcomp-proceedings.com/proc/p2015/SER2590.pdf) (PDF)

Just to show that this modeling approach is indeed actually used in practice, here is an example of a software (Oasys MassMotion) and how it could be used to model elevators: ["Oasys Software Blog: Modelling Lifts"](http://www.oasys-software.com/blog/2012/11/modelling-lifts/)

---

That is the computer science graduate way of doing this. What works almost as well in practice and requires a lot less skills and knowledge is that you come up with whatever you feel like (making common sense assumptions) and if somebody (in charge) complains you adjust the algorithm :-)

Comment: You can also learn the behavior of the people in the building. I guess most elevators don't do that though.

Comment: @Elazar Good point, an additional dimension with its own multitude of cons and pros: Where to put the intelligence, do it all in advance or put it into the object(s) and allow them to adapt. McDonalds stores are an example for up-front planning, Xerox PARC one for the latter, to look at human organizations as an example.